# ffprobe output text wrong encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

```
ffprobe -print_format json -show_format -sexagesimal -show_streams file.mp3
```

The output json is the wrong format and wrong text encoding:

```
... , "title": "繧ｫ繧､繝・, ...
```

In Explorer, the Properties show:

```
title: カイト
```

How do I fix this?

Test file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpLnwSpvipyw7pPSL2LYw8MMgQ8p1Vm0/view?usp=sharing)

```
ffmpeg version: ffmpeg-4.3-win64-static
```

Comment: On Linux using ffprobe 4.3.1 I see `"title": "カイト",`

Comment: problem from console read https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8890#comment:2

Comment: @TrươngQuốcKhánh, please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My report bug in ffmpeg page [ffprobe utf8 stdout on windows console is broken](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8890)

---

Update:
Goto `Control Panel\Clock and Region`
Click `Change date, time, or number format`
In `Region` window, click tab `Administrative` and click `Change system locale...`
Check the checkbox `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 .....`
Click `Ok` and restart computer.
Note: In console (cmd,...), don't forget change to support font
[image]